# Template metaprogramming. Conditional existence for class members

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming, sfinae

I wonder if it is possible to write a template class, having different members set in its compiled version.

For example, how it is achieved using inheritance:

```
/// These statistics are supported for all data types
struct StatsBase {
  size_t count;

  virtual void Describe() { print(count); }
};

/// These can describe almost all data types, but not all of them
template<DataType data_type>
struct StatsMinMax : public StatsBase {
  CppType<data_type> min;
  CppType<data_type> max;

  void Describe() override {
    StatsBase::Describe();
    print(min);
    print(max);
  }
};

/// These are for numeric data types only
template<DataType data_type>
struct StatsAll : public StatsMinMax<data_type> {
  CppType<data_type> sum;

  void Describe() override {
    StatsMinMax<data_type>::Describe();
    print(sum);
  }
}
```

And, suppose I have the following **constexpr** functions

```
constexpr bool IsMinMaxSupported(data_type dt) { /* details */ }
constexpr bool IsSumSupported(data_type dt) { /* details */ }
```

So, the question is whether it is possible to express in C++ something like this:

```
template<DataType data_type>
struct Stats {
  size_t count;
  CppType<data_type> min; // Must exist only in those instances, where IsMinMaxSupported(data_type) == true
  CppType<data_type> max; // Must exist only in those instances, where IsMinMaxSupported(data_type) == true
  CppType<data_type> sum; // Must exist only in those instances, where IsSumSupported(data_type) == true

  void Describe() { 
    print(count);
    if (IsMinMaxSupported(data_type)) {
      print(min);
      print(max);
    }
    if (IsSumSupported(data_type)) {
      print(sum);
    }
  }
};
```

Meaning that some of the fields mustn't physically exist in some cases (it is crucial for memory consumption). If it is possible, then will be method `Describe()` compiled as I wrote it, or should it have been rewritten (with proper specializations), using SFINAE?

Comment: Maybe a silly question: what is DataType ? is it an enumeration? If so,  what is the member "data_type min" ?

Comment: @alangab That looks like a typo to me. The only valid keywords for the first symbol inside the <> are `class` and `typename`.

Comment: @alangab, yes, it is an enumeration. I wrote so just to simplify the code a little bit, cuz it won't compile anyway. I've corrected the code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be achieved with template specialization:

```
template<typename DataType, bool x_min_max_supported> struct
StatsMinMax { /* empty */ };

template<typename DataType> struct
StatsMinMax<DataType , true>
{
    DataType min;
    DataType max;
};

...

template<DataType data_type>
struct Stats
: public StatsMinMax<DataType, IsMinMaxSupported(data_type)>
{
```

Comment: Answer is fine. But if you really want the granularity of 8 different permutations of the variable declarations, you might consider extending it to either multiple inheritance with 3 base classes, 1 per variable, or a cascade of template classes if you prefer cascades to multiple inheritance.

Comment: I've got you, thanks. But the answer isn't complete. The main concern was about the fields, but the question was about using them in methods too.

Comment: @Alexey You can put empty and non-empty `Describe` methods into those classes. Or use `if constexpr`.

Comment: The easiest way to tweak the methods might be to actually define the missing members, but as types (empty enums) rather than as values, or to define allong-side helper MemberExistsXxx enumerations, which could then be detected using C++17 if constexpr. Another way would be to define getter and setter methods in the base classes that return a default value or error/exception if the member does not exist, so the top-level code can get() even if the value does not exist..